# Ipad displaying wordpress site improperly. (Closing div?)

Tags: wordpress, ipad, web, format

So I am trying to format my site for ipads.  I am currently testing with an ipad mini.

I had an issue with widths and also everything being centered rather than aligned left.  I fixed this issue with this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=.60, user-scalable=1, minimum-scale=.60, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Now my problem is the content isn't being displayed properly.  It seems as if the main content-side div is being closed when it shouldn't be.  I have looked at the site with firebug and still can't find the issue.  Please if you have any info on this I would greatly appreciate it.

Here is the site:  http://www.webdesignog.com

Answer (score 0):

Here's your answer:

[W3 Validation of WebDesignOG.com](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.webdesignog.com/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Start by having valid HTML with a valid dtd. Fix all the errors you get on the validator. Right now I could see not one but several un-closed divs, at least from what the parser gets from your HTML.

The best thing you can do to see a website as you want it on almost every device/browser, is using a strict DOCTYPE and having no errors on validation.

HTH

Francisco

Comment: Thanks.  I'm pretty confused on where to even begin here.  Because I am using wordpress which is using all sorts of php.  I customized the theme to my likings and probably screwed some stuff up.  Although all display is working perfect on every browser except for the ipad/smartphones.

Comment: My php files which generate the html seem to be closing all divs.  Not sure what to do... :(